# Active class nav item based on retrieved url portion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add a css class (.active) on the appropriate navigation link.

My navigation:

```html
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <a href="index.php"><li id="Thuispagina">Thuispagina</li></a>
        <a href="../airsoft-nieuws"><li id="Nieuws">Nieuws</li></a>
        <a href="../airsoft-evenementen"><li id="Skirms">Skirms</li></a>
        <a href="../airsoft-reserveren"><li id="Reservatie">Reservatie</li></a>
        <a href="../airsoft-fotogalerij"><li id="Fotogalerij">Fotogalerij</li></a>
        <a href="../airsoft-contact"><li id="Contact">Contact</li></a>
        <a href="../airsoft-forum"><li id="Forum">Forum</li></a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

If I would be on one of the following pages: domain.com/airsoft-contact/index.php, domain.com/airsoft-contact/edit.php or domain.com/airsoft-contact/delete.php it should add the active class to the li item with id Contact

If I would be on one of the following pages: domain.com/airsoft-fotogalerij/index.php, domain.com/airsoft-fotogalerij/edit.php or domain.com/airsoft-fotogalerij/delete.php it should add the active class to the li item with id Fotogalerij

On the other hand there is one exception: the index.php page is not in any submap so the logic should make an exception there.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Only `<li>` can be a child of `<ul>`. Also, what JavaScript have you tried?

Comment: i think that you can figure out this alone

Comment: I only know php css and html.. js and javascript is so vague to me :( but I know my solution should lay into that zone

Comment: problem solved on my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the better or simple way is using jquery but u can do it with php too using a condition example `class="<?php if ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']=="ur script name"){ echo "active";}?>"` or u can use ternary operator for better views so this is a way, u can find others

Comment: this works like a charm dude! ty! :), now the only thing to do is to trim of the right part until the last / so it only checks for the folder where the php files are in

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement this (if you aren't an expert user) is to add in the navigation element a js like this for every link

```
if(window.location.href == "yourlink"){
 document.getElementById("elementid").class = "active";
}
```

Another way can be something like:

```js
var links = [ new Link("yoururl1", "yourelement1"), new Link("yoururl2", "yourelement2"), new Link("yoururl3", "yourelement3")];

for(link in links){
  if(link.url == window.location.href){
     document.getElementById(link.elementid).class = "active";
  }
}

function Link (url, elementid){
  this.url = url;
  this.elementid = elementid;
}
```

Comment: ty for you'Re input :) ... in the above solution it doesn't want to set the active class for the folowing reason: (index):88 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addClass' of null, besides I would like to check the url string part starting after the top level domain name (.be ) So I woun't have problems when users come thru https://www. or https//

Comment: but i'm not using addclass (?)